# Read txt file as PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read txt as PySpark dataframe which is separated by uneven spaces. I tried delimiter with one space but it's not aligned properly.

Sample TXT input:

```
id  daily_date  day_of_week fiscal_week fiscal_month    fiscal_year yearweek
1   2010-01-03  0   1   1   2010    201001
2   2010-01-04  1   1   1   2010    201001
3   2010-01-05  2   1   1   2010    201001
4   2010-01-06  3   1   1   2010    201001
5   2010-01-07  4   1   1   2010    201001
6   2010-01-08  5   1   1   2010    201001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace multiple spaces with single space using the RDD API, and convert the result to a dataframe.

```
import re

rdd = sc.textFile('file.csv')
header = rdd.take(1)[0]
df = rdd.filter(lambda r: r != header) \
        .map(lambda r: re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', r).split(' ')) \
        .toDF(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', header).split(' '))

df.show()
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------+
| id|daily_date|day_of_week|fiscal_week|fiscal_month|fiscal_year|yearweek|
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------+
|  1|2010-01-03|          0|          1|           1|       2010|  201001|
|  2|2010-01-04|          1|          1|           1|       2010|  201001|
|  3|2010-01-05|          2|          1|           1|       2010|  201001|
|  4|2010-01-06|          3|          1|           1|       2010|  201001|
|  5|2010-01-07|          4|          1|           1|       2010|  201001|
|  6|2010-01-08|          5|          1|           1|       2010|  201001|
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------+
```